# How to keep the user logged in in kivy app

Tags: python, android, kivy, sharedpreferences, pyjnius

I have made an app in kivy, once the user login into the account, I want to save his details in his Android itself. So that whenever he opens my app again , it will automatically check for the details from his Android itself. This will keep them logged in , even if they close the app.

How to achieve it, in kivy app?